# Anyway to get current usage stat from vCenter via REST API?

Tags: rest, vsphere, vcenter

I'm using REST API to develop a web-based private cloud management system that can monitor and have some automated functions like "auto-create VM as user want if there are enough resources" and "auto-remove unused VM for a time (e.g. 1 month)".

There are anyway to get some stat from vCenter like CPU, RAM, Storage usage to use for "auto-create VM if there are enough resources" cause I get appliance health it's show as "Green" not the values.

Update:
I had use this https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1cd28284-3b72-4885-9e31-d1c6d9e26686/71ef7304-a6c9-43b3-a3cd-868b2c236c81/doc/operations/com/vmware/appliance/monitoring.query-operation.html to get monitoring data but I don't know how to use these data values.

I thought the "16423596.0" was something like total memory in KB but I converted it to GB its not equal to actual memory on vCenter host.

[data got from REST by POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwjME.jpg)

My cloud environment contains 1 vCenter and 1 seperate ESXi as host.

ESXi spec:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz (8 Logical Processor)

4 GB Memory

402 GB Storage

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time, VM and host stats are not yet available through the REST API. Those stats can be pulled from the vSphere Web Services API, but it's SOAP based.